# How to get arount the limit of 20 entries?

Tags: python, django, api, twitter, limit

In the app I'm working on I'm showing tweets from a specific user, which works fine except that it's only showing the last 20 tweets. Is there a way of getting around this limit and if so how to do it?

**views.py:**

```
    user = twitter.User
    tweets = []
    statuses = t.GetUserTimeline(user)
    for s in statuses:
        text = linkify(s.text)
        tweets.append('<p>' + text + '</p>')
```

Comment: Please, specify details on `API` you are using or python wrappers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you get only 20 tweets? GetUserTimeline gives last 100 tweets, if you want, pass count=x, where x is number of tweets you want. Or am making a guess here, the user you are trying connect only has 20 tweets in his account.
see the link http://nullege.com/codes/search/twitter.Api.GetUserTimeline?fulldoc=1

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The user has actually alot more than 20 tweets. I'll try count=x!

Comment: Will do as soon as it's possible :)